# API fetches data, and succeeds on redux tools but shows nothing in the UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I am new to **MERN** stack and trying to `fetch` user data from the backend from **mongodb** and The **API** works fine and shows the user Details in the **redux tools** and shows the action as success but the details are not displaying in the user profile UI. I have attached the code for the **API, reducer, action** and also the frontend. Thank you in advance for the help

```
//GET profile details API
exports.getUserdetails =async (req,res)=>{
  try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
     res.status(200).json(user);
   } catch (err) {
     res.status(500).json({success:false, message: "User not found"});
   }
};
```

```
function Profile() {
**Userprofile front end**
  const { user,  isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);

  const dispatch= useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
    dispatch(detailsUser(user));
    }
  }, [ dispatch, isAuthenticated, user]);

  

  return (
          <div className='profile'>
            <h2 className="name">{user.firstname}{' '}{user.lastname}</h2>
            <h3 >@{user.email}</h3>
```

```
//LOGIN ACTION
export const signin = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: SIGNIN_REQUEST });
  
      const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } };
  
      const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/v1/login`, { email, password }, config);

      dispatch({ type: SIGNIN_SUCCESS, payload: data});
      
      

    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: SIGNIN_FAIL, payload: error.response.data.message });
    }
  };

//GET USER DETAILS ACTION
export const detailsUser = () => async (dispatch) => {

try {

    dispatch({ type: USER_DETAILS_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/profile`);
   
    dispatch({ type: USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data.user});
  } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: USER_REGISTER_FAIL, payload: error.response.data.message });
    }
};
```

```
//USER DETAILS REDUCER
 export const userDetailsReducer = (state = { user: {} }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case USER_DETAILS_REQUEST:
        return { 
          loading: true,
          isAuthenticated: false,
         };
      case USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
        return {  
           ...state,
          loading: false,
          isAuthenticated: true,
          user: action.payload 
        };
      case USER_DETAILS_FAIL:
        return {  
          
          loading: false,
          isAuthenticated: false,
          user: null,
          error: action.payload 
        };
      
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

```
//STORE.JS
const initialState={};
const reducer=combineReducers({
  userSignin: userSigninReducer,
  userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
  userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
});
```

```
//APP.JS
import store from './store';
import { detailsUser } from "./actions/userAction";

function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {

    store.dispatch(detailsUser());
  }, []);
  
 
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
       <Route path="/login" element={[<Header/>,<Login />]} /
       <Route path="/profile" element={[<Header/>,<Profile />]} />
             </Routes>
    </div>
   </BrowserRouter>
  
);
```

Comment: Looks like, you are trying to get **userDetails** data from **userSigninReducer** in the **profile** component, while **dispatch(detailsUser(user))** inserts the _API response_ to  **userDetailsReducer** via **user detail action**.

Comment: how can i solve it please?

Comment: Instead of getting **user** value from:  _const { user,  isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);_.  Get it like this in the **profile** component:  _const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.userDetails);_